# conversion of html string into java string removing html, css etc tags

Tags: java, android, html, css, jsoup

I am working on a project where data is coming from a server. In certain fields data is stored in html format. My problem is that i want to display that information in Android Text View. but not with this html part. However, I want to keep the Line break information intact So, that it can properly displayed to user. I have tried Jsoup.clean but it also left some style sheet data, like ,

elements etc
 One of sample string is :

```
&lt;ul style=&quot;list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; padding-top: 0px;     

    padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;
&lt;li style=&quot;line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;Offer is on a choice of veg or non-veg meals for Two
&lt;ul style=&quot;list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 14px; line-height: normal; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;
&lt;li style=&quot;line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Offer 1- Rs.499 Worth Rs. 1000:&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;nbsp;Veg Lunch OR Dinner for 2 Persons&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li style=&quot;line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Offer 2 &amp;ndash; Rs.599 Worth Rs. 1200:&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;nbsp;Non-Veg Lunch OR Dinner for 2 Persons&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;/li&gt;

&lt;li style=&quot;line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;Traditional restaurant serving authentic cuisine in mud pots&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li style=&quot;line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;Inclusive of all taxes and service charges&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li style=&quot;line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;upc gry sml&quot;&gt;Cost for 2: &lt;/span&gt;Rs. 700&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
```

after applying jsoup.clean the string becomes

```
 <ul style="list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin: 0px;"> <li style="line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Offer is on a choice of veg or non-veg meals for Two <ul style="list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 14px; line-height: normal; margin: 0px;"> <li style="line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"><strong>Offer 1- Rs.499 Worth Rs. 1000:</strong>&nbsp;Veg Lunch OR Dinner for 2 Persons</li> <li style="line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"><strong>Offer 2 &ndash; Rs.599 Worth Rs. 1200:</strong>&nbsp;Non-Veg Lunch OR Dinner for 2 Persons</li> </ul> </li> <li style="line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Traditional restaurant serving authentic cuisine in mud pots</li> <li style="line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Inclusive of all taxes and service charges</li> <li style="line-height: 18px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"><strong><span class="upc gry sml">Cost for 2: </span>Rs. 700</strong></li> </ul>
```

Please help me solving this issue.

Comment: Why down vote? Had I commit any mistake? Please tell me so that I can avoid it in future.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`html.fromHtml(string);`

Comment: Sorry, but what is html in html.fromHtml(string).